# Setting an existing variable to itself's first element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I'm not sure why this isn't working in rails, however it works in IRB.

I'm doing something like:

```
response = response.first
```

`response` is an array with hashes.

In irb, when trying to simulate this, it works fine.

e.g:

```
>> a = [{'a'=>3}]
=> [{"a"=>3}]    
>> a = a.first   
=> {"a"=>3}
```

However in debugger mode, in cucumber (in my step definition), i get this when doing the above statement:

e.g:

```
(rdb:1) response = response.first
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass
(rdb:1) response
nil
```

Then, `response` gets set to `nil`.

Why are the behaviors different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you 100% sure that `response` is a *local variable*? If `response` were a *method* that would explain the behavior you are seeing: the *local variable* `response` shadows the *method* `response`. If you want to call the `response` method you need to explicitly tell Ruby that want the method by either supplying an argument list or a receiver:

```
response = response().first
# or
response = self.response.first
```

Comment: right on the money, :) .. i figured it out and response was a method in a different file. d'oh..